# ArrayList of classes without having to create an instance of this class first

Tags: java, arraylist

So if I have a class of Person, where you can define their name, age and date of birth.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String dOB;

    public Person (String name, int age, String dateOfBirth)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        dOB = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Then in another class of Memberships, I have an arrayList called Members. I know how to add a Person  by:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Memberships
{
    private ArrayList<Person> members;

    public Memberships()
    {
        members = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public void addMember(Person person)
    {
        members.add(person);
    }
}
```

However how do I add a member without separately creating an instance of Person.
So starting with:

```
    public void addMember(String name, int age, String dOB)
    {
    }
```

This is where I get stuck I have no idea how to take these values to create a Person to add to my members ArrayList.

@dehlen Sorry!

```
public void addNewMember(String name, int age, String dOB)
{
    Person p = new Person(name, age, dOB);

    for (Person pers : members)
    {
        if (pers.getName().equals(name))
        {
            System.out.print("This member is already included.");
        }
        else
        {
            members.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

So I did this, however the Person is never added? I'm confused as to why?

Comment: `members.add(new Person(name, age, dOB))`? Incidentally, read about Programming to the Interface.

Comment: @LibbieThomas where does memberships come from ? the correct way is  to implement as i stated in my answer. You have to break out of the for loop if you found a duplicate.

Comment: @dehlen sorry was just trying some other things to see to try and get it to work, I've put pers back in now.. Break out of the loop? Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean by that to make it just exactly as I already posted in my answer. If you found a duplicate end the method by sending a return; After the for loop you can add the person object since you did not end the method execution because you have found a duplicate. What the method does i posted is: Go through all members, found a duplicate--> stop adding a new person. If i looked at all members and there is no duplicate --> only then add a new person object.

Comment: @LibbieThomas Look at my answer i added comments to my code so you can better understand whats going on.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: @dehlen sorry if I wanted to do the same thing again, but using the addMember(Person person) how do I then check the values are not repeated? I tried if (pers().equals(person.name)) but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **need** to create an instance of Person, since this is what your `ArrayList` expects.
Here is how you can complete your task:

```
public void addMember(String name, int age, String dOB)
{
    Person p = new Person(name,age,dOB);
    members.add(p);
}
```

To make sure you do not add duplicates to your `ArrayList` you could iterate over your `ArrayList` and look if there is a `Person` object with the same values already in it.

```
public void addMember(String name, int age, String dOB)
    {
    //Create a new Person instance with given parameters
    Person p = new Person(name,age,dOB);

    //Loop through existing Person instances in ArrayList
    for (Person pers : members){
        //If there exists a Person with the same name
        if (pers.getName().equals(name)) {
            //We can stop searching for a duplicate and leave the method
            return;
        }
    }
    //Since we did not exit the method above we did not found any duplicate, therefore it is safe to add our Person instance to our ArrayList
    members.add(p);
}
```

Of course this only checks whether there is a Person with the same name. But I with the help of this code you can accomplish also to check further properties.

Also I use a method called `getName(`) which is called a getter. This method has to be specified in your Person model class:

```
public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

As @BorisTheSpider pointed out correctly there is a better approach to test equality.
You <strike>can</strike>/**should** override the `equals()` method of your model class like so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object person)
{
    boolean same = false;

    if (person != null && person instanceof Person)
    {
        same = this.name == ((Person) person).name;
    }

    return same;
}
```

Then you can use use the `contains()` method as following:

```
members.contains(p);
```

To check your other properties too you should implement the logic in the overidden `equals()` method.

Comment: Actually he was asking exactly this: "This is where I get stuck I have no idea how to take these values to create a Person to add to my members ArrayList."

Comment: You're right, my mistake. You actually answers that, +.

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering extending from this I don't want a person to be added with the same name, age and date of birth. I guess you use .equals() right? But how do I do this?

Comment: @LibbieThomas see my edited answer. You are on the right track.

Comment: @LibbieThomasn then a `List` isn't the right collection to use. You should use a `Set`. This guarantees uniqueness by `equals` and `add` is `O(1)`. With a `List`, the above method is `O(n)` - which is terrible.

Comment: @dehlen I would never recommend this method to guarantee uniqueness, it's slow and clumsy. First there is already a `Collection.contains` method for exactly this, and second; a `List` can only do this is linear time. I'm sorry but I'm going to have to reverse my upvote to a downvote in light of this update.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are right. I thought overriding the equals method was a bit to advanced for the OP. But the approach is way better than mine. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @dehlen The OP asked that _none_ of the fields are the same. Also overriding `equals` without `hashCode` is a **big** no-no. Further, `List.contains` is `O(n)` - `Set.contains` is `O(1)` so I would recommend using a `Set` in any case.

Comment: Well the OP asked to not add duplicate objects to the list. This can be accomplished by either checking if all properties are equal (if all are equals do not add it to the list) or one property isn't equal (one property is not equals so add it to the list). Concerning the missing hashCode you are right, I forgot that. The method hashCode() should also be overidden in the model class. Concerning the Set/List discussion the Set is the better option but since the OP is using a List I made the example using a list.

Comment: I can't use @Override as this is a uni assignment hence why I'm also using an ArrayList not a set (Sorry about that!) it doesn't particularly matter if its slow and clumsy, just needs to work on a basic level I've been trying to just use .equals() is there any way for it to work this way?

Comment: look at my answer I already told you how to do it this way. Just iterate over your members array and compare. I showed you how to do it in the second version of `addMember()` method. But again I have to admit that Boris the Spider is right and you should not get used to it since his approach is better. If you have to do it because of the uni assignment then you have the answer however.

Comment: Ok, thank you; public void addNewMember(String name, int age, String dOB)
    {
        Person p = new Person(name, age, dOB);
        
        for (Person pers : members)
        {
            if (pers.getName().equals(name))
            {
                System.out.print("This member is already included.");
            }
            else
            {
                members.add(p);
            }
        }
       
    } So I attempted this, but it never adds anyone, why? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, sorry! Just added it to my first question, is the for loop not working or something for some reason as the Person is never added to the members arrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `Person` instance, and then you can pass it into your existing `addMember` method that takes a person.

```
public void addMember(String name, int age, String dateOfBirth) {
    this.addMember(new Person(name, age, dateOfBirth);
}
```